# ¿Como puedo convertir este código para que sea totalmente en bucle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

el problema de mi pregunta es que no se como convertir este codigo para que sean todo en bucle, utilizando el visual studio windows forms, lo siguiente es el enunciado.
****hallar un numero entero entre -100 y 100000, encontrar la mayor cifra, la menor cifra, la suma de sus cifras no primas, la multiplicación de sus cifras primas y todo aquello dividirla entre la suma de sus cifras pares.****
y yo llegue a "hacerlo" pero de otra manera, y lo tenia que hacer en bucle.

```
             long numero6 = Convert::ToInt64(txtnumero->Text);
             long mayor, menor, cifra1, cifra2, cifra3, cifra4, cifra5, cifra6;
             cifra1 = numero6 % 10; numero6 /= 10;
             cifra2 = numero6 % 10; numero6 /= 10;
             cifra3 = numero6 % 10; numero6 /= 10;
             cifra4 = numero6 % 10; numero6 /= 10;
             cifra5 = numero6 % 10; numero6 /= 10;
             cifra6 = numero6 % 10; numero6 /= 10;

             mayor = menor = cifra1;
             if (cifra2>mayor)mayor = cifra2; if (cifra2>mayor)mayor = cifra3; if (cifra4>mayor)mayor = cifra4;
             if (cifra5>mayor)mayor = cifra5; if (cifra6>mayor)mayor = cifra6;

             if (cifra2<menor)menor = cifra2; if (cifra3<menor)menor = cifra3; if (cifra4<menor)menor = cifra4;
             if (cifra5<menor)menor = cifra5; if (cifra6<menor)menor = cifra6;

             txtnumeroMayor->Text = mayor + "";
             txtnumeroMenor->Text = menor + "";

             long sumacifraspares = 0, multiplicacioncifrasprimas = 1, sumacifranoprimas = 0;

             if (cifra1 == 2 || cifra1 == 3 || cifra1 == 5 || cifra1 == 7) { sumacifraspares += cifra1; multiplicacioncifrasprimas *= cifra1; }
             else sumacifranoprimas += cifra1;
             if (cifra2 == 2 || cifra2 == 3 || cifra2 == 5 || cifra2 == 7) { sumacifraspares += cifra2; multiplicacioncifrasprimas *= cifra2; }
             else sumacifranoprimas += cifra2;
             if (cifra3 == 2 || cifra3 == 3 || cifra3 == 5 || cifra3 == 7) { sumacifraspares += cifra3; multiplicacioncifrasprimas *= cifra3; }
             else sumacifranoprimas += cifra3;
             if (cifra4 == 2 || cifra4 == 3 || cifra4 == 5 || cifra4 == 7) { sumacifraspares += cifra4; multiplicacioncifrasprimas *= cifra4; }
             else sumacifranoprimas += cifra4;
             if (cifra5 == 2 || cifra5 == 3 || cifra5 == 5 || cifra5 == 7) { sumacifraspares += cifra5; multiplicacioncifrasprimas *= cifra5; }
             else sumacifranoprimas += cifra5;
             if (cifra6 == 2 || cifra6 == 3 || cifra6 == 5 || cifra6 == 7) { sumacifraspares += cifra6; multiplicacioncifrasprimas *= cifra6; }
             else sumacifranoprimas += cifra6;

             txtnumeroSumaCPrimas->Text = sumacifraspares + "";
             txtnumeroMultiplicacion->Text = ((multiplicacioncifrasprimas*1.0) / (sumacifranoprimas*1.0)) + "";
```

Comment: **"Hallar un número entero entre -100 y 100000"** a qué se refiere? qué condiciones son las que vas a buscar? Qué número se debe obtener? O el bucle debe ir dentro de ese rango?

Comment: eso es una condición para que los numero -100 hasta 100000, los numeros dentro de esa condición se deber permitir, y los que no estan dentro de ese numero no lo valida.